# This sentence sounds weird

Tags: grammar

I saw a tattoo like shown below.

Everything what you own 
            owns you

To me it sounds better when you take out the word "what".
Does it matter whether you use it? Does the meaning change?
Also should there be a comma before the word "owns"?

Thanks.

Comment: It's ungrammatical. You could either leave out _what_, or replace _what_ with _that_.

So you'd get:
_everything you own..._ or _Everything that you own..._

Comment: It seems to me as if the phrase infers a meaning of "Everything that you own owns you."

Comment: Using "what" in this way is a dialectual thing, maybe Cockney? It's not standard English.

Answer (score 1):

It should read "Everything that you own, owns you."
The comma helps prevent confusion between the two words.

Comment: The comment has already said as much; if you choose to repeat it in an answer, you need to add supporting evidence.

Comment: @PeterJohnmeyer Existence of answers in the comments should not prevent one from posting those answers inside the actual answer box where it can be vetted. To this particular answer, I do not see the need for further supporting evidence.